# Subspace union of connected components equivalent to continuous function to $\{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $A$ be a locally connected topological space and $B$ a subspace.
I want to prove the equivalence of the following two statements:

> (i) $B$ is a union of connected components of $A$.
>   (ii) there is a continuous function $p:A\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $p(b)=0$ for $b\in B$ and $p(b)=1$ for $b\notin B$.

What I know:
Locally connected means that for all $a\in A$ and neighbourhoods $N$ of $a$ there is a connected neighbourhood $N'$ such that $N'\subseteq N$.
A connected component of $A$ is a connected subspace $C$ such that there is no strict larger connected subspace $C\subset C'$ in $A$.
However, I dont see how these can help me prove the equivalence, maybe somebody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: The functions perhaps obscure what’s going on just a bit, so let’s get rid of them.

- Show that $(ii)$ is equivalent to the assertion that $B$ is a clopen (closed and open) subset of $A$.

Since components are always closed, a good first step would be to show that each component of $A$ is open.

- Show that if each component of $A$ is open, then each union of components of $A$ is clopen in $A$. Conclude that if each component of $A$ is open, then $(i)$ implies $(ii)$.

To show that each component of $A$ is open, suppose that $C$ is a component of $A$, and let $x\in C$; we want to show that $x$ has a nbhd contained in $C$. Since $A$ is locally connected, $x$ has some connected nbhd $N$.

- Show that $C\cup N$ is connected.
- Clearly $C\subseteq C\cup N$, so what can you infer about $N$?

All that remains is to show that $(ii)$ implies $(i)$.

- Show that every clopen subset of $A$ is a union of components.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you maybe complete your answer?

Comment: @Cognomen: This is already a pretty big hint. Can you do any of the five steps that I suggested?

Comment: The first, fourth and fifth aren't that clear to me.

Comment: @Cognomen: For the first, remember that if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}[A]$ is closed in $X$ whenever $A$ is closed in $Y$, and $f^{-1}[A]$ is open in $X$ whenever $A$ is open in $Y$. Now consider the case $Y=\{0,1\}$ and $A=\{0\}$ or $A=\{1\}$. For the fourth, recall that the component containing a point $x$ is the *largest* connected subset of the space containing $x$. For the fifth, show that if $G$ is a clopen subset of $A$, and $K$ is a connected subset of $A$, then it’s impossible to have both $K\cap G$ and $K\setminus G$ non-empty.

Comment: Thank you again, I still have a few unclear things :( I hope you dont mind.   For the third, aren't intersections of connected subsets always connected?  For the fourth, does that mean that $N$ is empty? And could you explain the fifth a bit more?

Comment: @Cognomen: The intersection of two connected sets can be disconnected: $\bigcirc$ and $/$ are connected, but their intersection (as in $\varnothing$) is a pair of points. In any case, in the third point it’s the union in which we’re interested, and it’s connected because the intersection is non-empty, not because it’s connected: it may not be connected. For the fourth: no, it just says that $C\cup N$ must be equal to $C$, which means that $N\subseteq C$, and that’s exactly what we want: $x$ has a nbhd, $N$, contained in $C$. Since this is true of every $x\in C$, $C$ is open. For the fifth, ...

Comment: ... the idea is to show that if $G$ is clopen, no connected subset $C$ of $X$ (and hence no component) can intersect both $G$ and $X\setminus G$. If it did, $C\cap G$ would be a non-empty, clopen *proper* subset of $C$; why is that impossible?

Comment: I'm not sure why thats impossible...

Comment: @Cognomen: If $C$ is a connected set, and $H$ is a non-empty, clopen proper subset of $C$, let $K=C\setminus H$. Then $C=H\cup K$, $H\cap K=\varnothing$, and $H$ and $K$ are non-empty open subsets of $C$ ...

Comment: I understand everything you say now, but I only don't really see why not both $C\cap G$ and $C\backslash G$ non-empty implies that $G$ is a union of components?

Comment: @Cognomen: (I was offline yesterday.) It doesn’t directly: it implies that $C$ is not connected, which is a contradiction. Thus, every component of the space must belong either to $G$ or to $X\setminus G$, and $G$ is therefore the union of the components contained in it.